# Best Practice for Persistent Login Using Nextjs 13 and Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I'm using Nextjs 13 and Firebase to let users login to my website using their google account.

I have a component called GoogleSignin.jsx that properly logs the user in.  console.log(user) shows the user details.

```
   "use client"

   import {auth} from "@/lib/firebase";
   import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

   const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

   const googleLogin = (e) => {
       console.log("Button Clicked");
       console.log(e);
       e.preventDefault()
       signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider)
       .then((result) => {
         // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
         const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
         const token = credential.accessToken;
         // The signed-in user info.
         const user = result.user;
         console.log(user);
         // ...
       }).catch((error) => {
         // Handle Errors here.
         const errorCode = error.code;
         const errorMessage = error.message;
         // The email of the user's account used.
         const email = error.customData.email;
         // The AuthCredential type that was used.
         const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
         // ...   
       });
   }

   const GoogleSignIn = () => {
 
   return (
       <div>
           <button onClick={googleLogin} className="mb-6 flex w-full items-center justify-center    rounded-md bg-white p-3 text-base font-medium text-body-color shadow-one hover:text-primary dark:bg-[#242B51] dark:text-body-color dark:shadow-signUp dark:hover:text-white">
                  
                  Sign in with Google
                </button>
       </div>
   )
   }

   export default GoogleSignIn
```

My Header component has a "signin" button that takes the user to a signin page that displays the above GoogleSignIn component.  After the user signs in, the Header component checks the currentUser variable and changes the "signin" button to a "Dashboard" button that shows the users information stored in a FireStore database.

I use the following code to populate the currentUser variable. I have removed the Header code that is not related to getting the currentUser.

```
import {auth} from "@/lib/firebase";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const { currentUser } = getAuth()
```

After the google user signin popup window closes, console.log will show the user detail but the webpage will not update automatically.  I have to move the mouse over other links in the header before the user is displayed in the header.  The local server window shows components being loaded and then the user is displayed.

How do I make this automatic?

Also, my Hero section has the same signin button as the Header.  I added the same code that I used in the Header but the Hero section but the currentUser variable is always null even when the Header shows the user logged in.

How do I get the currentUser variable to be global the the whole website?  My app directory has

> head.jsx

> layout.jsx

> page.jsx

> providers.jsx

Do I have to define the currentUser in providers.jsx?  If so, how does that look?

Comment: So I removed  import {auth} from "@/lib/firebase";
and added const auth = getAuth();
and it seems to be keeping me logged in.

Comment: I noticed a behavior with my webpage.  If I scroll the page, my Header component changes the Header (NavBar) to continue to appear at the top of the page.  And this causes the User to show in the Header.  So I think I need to refresh the Header and Hero component....